# Json data in Structure table

Tags: python, json

I extracted the data from JSON and now but I need the results in a table format. where i am wrong please help me out

```
import requests
import json

 url = 
 response = requests.get(url)

 if response.status_code == 200:
if response.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    formatted_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    print(formatted_data)
else:
    raise Exception("Response content type is not JSON")
else:
print("Error: Unable to retrieve data from API.")
```

[image]

I need output like this

```
ID    Category          _Value   Count
135   Remaining Budget  Null       3
136   Remaining Budget  9216.0     3
```

Comment: Doesn't `data = json.loads(response.text)` create a proper python data structure?

Comment: its does but I need the results in a table format.

Comment: For display or do you mean as a pandas DataTable?

Comment: Pandas Datatable 
check my output i want that output

Comment: After importing pandas you can try `df = pandas.DataTable(response.json())`

Comment: i did but still not showing me result in table format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253032/discussion-between-assad-amjad-and-jonsg).

Comment: `df = pandas.DataFrame(response.json()).set_index("ID")` should work. If not, then perhaps the returned json is more complicated that what is shown. You haven't given us much to to on here.

Comment: Please read about a [mcve]. We cannot see your full JSON response (as text, please, not an image). And we do not know what URL you are using

Answer (score 0):

#### The exact indenting is crucial in python

It works if laid out like this

```
import requests
import json

url = "<URL for the API>"
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
  if response.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
      data = json.loads(response.text)
      formatted_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
      print(formatted_data)
  else:
      raise Exception("Response content type is not JSON")
else:
  print("Error: Unable to retrieve data from API.")
```

#### To format a table of output, you can use `print(f"...")`

```
print("  ID Category                      _Value Count")
for row in data["data"]:
    print(f"{row['id']:4} {row['Category']:24} {row['_Value'] or 0:11.2f} {row['count'] or 0:>5}")
```

Example output:

```
  ID Category                       _Value Count
   1 Planned_Budget                   0.00     1
   2 Planned_Budget                   0.00     1
   3 Planned_Budget                   0.00     1
   4 Planned_Budget                   0.00     1
   5 Planned_Budget                   0.00     1
   6 Planned_Budget                   0.00     1
...
 136 Planned_Budget                   0.00     1
   1 Budget With GNA             191520.00     2
   2 Budget With GNA              10146.00     2
   3 Budget With GNA              14592.00     2
   4 Budget With GNA               8956.98     2
   5 Budget With GNA              10954.60     2
```

Comment: I know my code is working fine, but I need the results in a table format.

Comment: Ah, I don't think that was originally in the question - Now updated with a table format